# Pattern of falling objects for a particular level

Tags: java, android, box2d, game-physics, tiled

*Note: Please refer to the attached image for better understanding.*

I need to have a particular pattern of falling objects for a particular level, therefore I want to know if I should use tiled map with objects drawn or use code to create pattern for each level? Should I use Tiled map or write in code for moving object patterns

Please note: Each falling object falls at fix x-axis,

Only three objects falling: rectangle, circle and square.

*Currently using Math.random x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your own preference. Do you want to see the objects and their position while you edit the falling sequence, or are you fine just tweaking some numbers and probably trying rather more often whether it feels right in the game?

Also maybe the random aspect of the falling objects actually makes your game more interesting? Of course you would want to introduce some heuristics in your random choosing of objects and falling locations, to make sure the player has a chance of avoiding them. If you choose to have predefined levels, I would suggest you throw in an endless random play mode as well that gradually becomes more difficult.

Good luck with your game!

Comment: Thanks Bro.So what is more efficient? Tiled or code.

Comment: Both approaches can be implemented efficiently or inefficiently. I don't see this as a deciding factor here.